Question concerning center of mass argument
Suppose I have a vector function $\vec{v} : S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined for $\vec{y} \in S^2$ by \begin{equation}\vec{v}(\vec{y}) = \int_\Omega \vec{x}\tilde{G}(\theta)d\mu,\label{1}\end{equation}where $\theta$ measures the angle between $\vec{y}$ and the integration variable $\vec{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ represent some set of Cartesian coordinates. Assume we have $\vec{y_0}$ such that $\vec{v}(\vec{y_0}) = \alpha \vec{y_0}$ for some nonzero $\alpha$. Here, $\Omega \subset S^2$.
Now let $R$ be a $3x3$ rotation matrix with $\vec{y_0}$ as its last row. Define new cartesian coordinates $x_i' = \sum_j^3R_{ij}x_j$ so that for $\theta$ measured from $\vec{y_0}$, $$\int_\Omega x_i'\tilde{G}(\theta)d\mu = \sum_j^1R_{ij}\int_\Omega x_j\tilde{G}(\theta)d\mu = [R\vec{v}(\vec{y_0})]_i = [\alpha R \vec{y_0}]_i, \ \ i = 1,2,3.$$
I have understood these equalities. Now, I need help to see why we have these two (please attention on $i$) $$[\alpha R \vec{y_0}]_i = [\alpha \widehat{e}_3]_i=0, \ \ i =1,2.$$I see that if we have $R\vec{y_0} = \widehat{e}_3$ then we get the zeros. The authors only say "since $R$ is an orthogonal matrix and hence its first $n$ rows are orthogonal to its last row." Is this supposed to help?
I believe $\widehat{e}_3$ is the essentially the vector that points upwards so that $[\widehat{e}_3]_1 = [\widehat{e}_3]_2 = 0$. Also, with $R$ I think they mean $$R = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\ (y_0)_1& (y_0)_2 & (y_0)_3\end{pmatrix},$$so that $$R\vec{y_0} = \begin{pmatrix}(y_0)_1\cos \theta - (y_0)_2\sin\theta\\ (y_0)_1\sin \theta + (y_0)_2\cos\theta\\ \|\vec{y_0}\|^2\end{pmatrix}.$$Since $\vec{v}$ acts on $S^2$ then $\|\vec{y_0}\| = 1$ and we get $1$ in the last coordinate of the previous vector. But what about the other two?? why are they supposed to be zero so that we get $\widehat{e}_3$??
ps.: The authors (pp.1060) claim these as part of a center of mass type argument. It would be splendid if anyone could share some words on the meaning of the definition for $\vec{v}$ and what does it mean physically if it vanishes.
Thank you!
Edit: Well, if we have a vector $\vec{y_0}$ then it might be possible to find $\theta$, hence a rotation matrix, so that after applying it to $\vec{y_0}$ we are basically pointing upwards. Is this what they mean? and, which I think obviously yes, can we find such an angle $\theta$?
